# how to capture screen shot of packaged app in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os, package-development, chromium-tabs

we are developing some packaged app on chromium os... and the requirement is to capture the screen shot of my packaged app gui...

there is no chrome api in chrome apps to capture it from app itself...

but there is an api chrome.tab.captureVisibleTab in chrome extensions. but that too take screen shots of browser tabs only not of the packaged app

please help how to take screenshot of app ui?

Answer (score 0):

See chrome.desktopCapture if you want to take a screen shot pragmatically with your app.